# From a given list, remove all even numbers(including 0) and print out the resulting list

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
input_list = [22,456,3465,456,6543,546,345]
for num in input_list:
    if num==0 or num%2==0:
        input_list.remove(num)
```

Could you please tell me what is the problem in this code?
It is not removing second 456 from the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are removing an item while iterating over the list.

So when the num become `22` then `22` will be removed and `456` become index `0` in your list, in the next iteration the for loop looks for index `1` which is `3465`.

Try this:

```
input_list = [i for i in input_list if i%2 == 1]
```

Comment: this is a very classic duplicate, you probably know it since you answered it very quickly. Please vote to close instead of answering.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre In the first part, I explained OP's problem. but you are the moderator. are you still prefer to close this? You are the master.

Comment: You can vote to close as duplicate without being moderator. I did this with my gold python badge only. There's no moderator power involved here.

Comment: I know, but I thought the OP's problem is the problem of his code, not to achieve the goal. I will look more carefully. Thanks for your comment, You are one the best moderator, I voted for you ;)